# visual studio solution configuration value in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, configuration

I would like to know if there is a way to get the solution configuration name (debug, release, etc) in the program maybe in a #define ?

I found on the forum this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049471/determine-solutions-configuration-visual-studio) but the litle function doesn't work for me.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `YOUR_FANCY_NAME="$(ConfigurationName)"` in [Configuration Properties] -> [C/C++] -> [Preprocessor] -> [Preprocessor Definitions].

If you don't need the exact name and only want to determine if the current build is a debug build, you can use the preprocessor define `_DEBUG`:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
// stuff
#endif
```

Comment: There's also the standard `NDEBUG`, which is defined for Release builds. Importantly, `assert` is disabled when `NDEBUG` is defined.

Comment: @MSalters the standard doesn't know of any build configurations. It only states that `<cassert>` will behave differently if `NDEBUG` is defined.